# Plotting $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}z^{n}$ for $|z|<1$ (the natural boundary): Coding

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions, matlab

As part of my tutorial, I would like to show the plots of a)$-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}z^{n}$ and b)$Log(1-z)=log(|z|)+iArg(z)$, to drive home the point of analytic continuation.

Plotting the Log is easy but not the power series. Any suggestions for Matlab, mathematica or c++?

So far I've been trying with the symbolic sum function, but it was too heavy for my machine. I might leave it for few hours to run.

Any quicker ways?

Specifically I want to plot $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}r^{n}cos(n\theta)$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}r^{n}sin(n\theta)$ separately.

Here is a graph of a natural boundary image I found online. [image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you think is fairly easy in  Matlab too?

Comment: Should be fairly easy in Matlab also (of course it depends on how accurate you want the plot - but I assume this is just for illustration), but it's so long time ago since I touched upon Matlab so I don't know the best way to do it there.

Comment: Btw it might be easier to plot $f(z) = -\log(1-z)$ as this function agrees with the power-series for all $|z| < 1$. It will be faster to compute and you will not have any numerical problems with cancellation in the computation of the sum. You can see a plot of the real-part [here](http://folk.uio.no/hansw/replot.png) and the imaginary part [here](http://folk.uio.no/hansw/implot.png). (I removed the comment above as this is not a good way to do it - explicitly summing the series is bound to lead to numerical problems)

Comment: yeah thanks I forgot to correct it.

Comment: ... and note that the unit circle is not a natural boundary for that series ...